# http POST doesn't have form data when I access the site from Mobile browser

Tags: python, html, post

I am trying to host simple html page using python socket programming. The html page is simple form to get username. I accessed the site from PC and entered the data in the textbox. When I clicked the button, I got the POST method to my python terminal along with the form data I entered in the textbox. **The same is not happening when I accessed the same page from my phone browser. I can't get the form data**

Below is the python code:

```
from socket import *
import os

def func_getorpost(msg):
    spl = msg.find('\n')
    get_list = msg[0:spl].split(' ')
    proc_msg = msg[spl+1:].split('\r\n')[:-2]
    the_dic = dict([i.split(': ') for i in proc_msg])
    return (get_list,the_dic)

user_dic = {'dxc161630': '192.168.0.7'}
file_ = input('Html page  to bind: ')
_server = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
print('Server IP: ' +gethostbyname(gethostname()) +',1234')
try:
    _server.bind((gethostbyname(gethostname()),1234))  # we can socket module to get the current ip address. port is default to 1234
except:
    print('Socket Error')
    sys.exit(-1)

_server.listen(10)

while True:
    print()
    conn, addr = _server.accept()
    client_msg = conn.recv(4096).decode()
    print(client_msg)
    if 'GET' in client_msg:
        a_list,a_dic = func_getorpost(client_msg) # function to parse client_msg GET
        #print(a_list)
        #print(a_dic)
        #This try is for checking the presence files needed for the website
        try:
            if(a_list[1] == '/'):
                fp1 = open(os.getcwd()+a_list[1]+file_,'r')
            else:
                fp1 = open(os.getcwd()+'/'+a_list[1],'r')
        except IOError:
            print(a_list[1][:30]+'.... not found')
            fp1 = open(os.getcwd()+'\\temp','a+') # dont want to leave fp1 an empty thing
        # This try will check the encoding part
        try:
            msg_ = fp1.read().encode()
        except:
            msg_=b''
            print('>>>>>Encode Fail<<<<<<')
            #This try will ensure the accept part in the a_dic ie in get message.
        try:
            conn.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: '+a_dic['Accept'].split(',')[0].encode()+b'\n\n')
        #has a "Accept" header contains the file type such as type\html, application\xml etc,.
        except:
            conn.send(b'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\n')
            print("No accept part")
        conn.sendall(msg_)
        conn.close()
        fp1.close()
    elif 'POST' in client_msg:
        # Separate client_msg to get our msg
        our_msg = client_msg.split('\r\n\r\n')
        #print(our_msg)
        if(our_msg[1]==''):
            print('No msg coming')
            conn.close()        
        else:
            our_msg = our_msg[1].split('=')[1]
            print(our_msg)
            if our_msg in list(user_dic.keys()) or addr[0] in list(user_dic.values()):
                conn.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n')
                conn.send(b'<html><body><p>Choose different username or u already login to the server using this ip address</p></body></html>')
                conn.close()
            else:
                user_dic[our_msg] = addr[0]
            print(user_dic)
```

Below is the simple html code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
  <div>
    <label for="say">Username?</label>
    <input name="user" id="user" value="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Send my greetings</button>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your form doesn't seem to send data anywhere. Is there some javascript that you haven't included?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When specified with no attributes,the <form> data is sent to the same page that the form is present on. And I am already getting the data when I am opening the site in my PC. Uploaded the POST output image here: https://ibb.co/iv72OF   @Angrysheep

Comment: I imagine that your server is picking up the post because you're running the html on the same machine. Is that correct? Since your phone's browser is not on the same machine, form data is not accessible. I think you'll want to look into adding an 'action' attribute to your form, and point it at your server. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you @Angrysheep . Yeah I am running from the same machine. Let me try with  the javascript then.

Comment: @Angrysheep I tried the same page from  different PC without any action attribute. It worked. I got the form data. The problem is with mobile only.